# How can I show which WHERE condition matched?

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT
  id, text, the_match
FROM
  comments
WHERE
  (lower(text) LIKE '%excellent%'
   OR lower(text) LIKE '%great%'
   OR lower(text) LIKE '%good%') AS the_match
ORDER BY len(text) ASC
```

The SQL is invalid. `the_match` is not a valid column. I'm trying to display which condition in the `WHERE` clause caused a match. How can I do this?

Comment: What if all three conditions match?

Comment: @TheImpaler Then the first match should be returned.

Comment: Then all three answers are correct. I upvoted them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly (as you've seen). One way to address these types of issues is to use a `case` expression with the same conditions in the select list:

```sql
SELECT
  id, text, CASE WHEN lower(text) LIKE '%excellent%' THEN 'excellent condition'
                 WHEN lower(text) LIKE '%great%'     THEN 'great condition'
                 WHEN lower(text) LIKE '%good%'      THEN 'good condition'
            END AS condition
FROM
  comments
WHERE
  (lower(text) LIKE '%excellent%'
   OR lower(text) LIKE '%great%'
   OR lower(text) LIKE '%good%') AS the_match
ORDER BY len(text) ASC
```

To avoid duplicating logic, you could move this to a subquery:

```sql
SELECT    id, text, condition
FROM      (SELECT id, 
                  text, 
                  CASE WHEN LOWER(text) LIKE '%excellent%' THEN 'excellent'
                       WHEN LOWER(text) LIKE '%great%'     THEN 'great'
                       WHEN LOWER(text) LIKE '%good%'      THEN 'good'
                  END AS condition
           FROM   comments ) t
WHERE    condition IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY LEN(text) ASC
```

Comment: The code layout hurts my eyes, but at least it's DRY

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    id,
    text,
    CASE WHEN LOWER(text) LIKE '%excellent%' THEN 'excellent'
         WHEN LOWER(text) LIKE '%great%'     THEN 'great'
         WHEN LOWER(text) LIKE '%good%'      THEN 'good' END the_match
FROM comments
WHERE
    LOWER(text) LIKE '%excellent%' OR
    LOWER(text) LIKE '%great%' OR
    LOWER(text) LIKE '%good%'
ORDER BY
    LEN(text);
```

If you instead want a label for every record in your `comments` table, then just delete the `WHERE` clause.  In that case, the `the_match` field would be `NULL` for non matching records.

Comment: First answer given here by several minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Translate the `where` into a `case`:

```
SELECT
  id, text, 
  case
    when lower(text) LIKE '%excellent%' then 'excellent'
    when lower(text) LIKE '%great%' then 'great'
    else 'good' end as the_match
FROM
  comments
WHERE
  lower(text) LIKE '%excellent%'
   OR lower(text) LIKE '%great%'
   OR lower(text) LIKE '%good%'
ORDER BY len(text) ASC
```

Note that `the_match` returns the “highest” priority word found. ie if `text` had both "great" and "good" `the_match` will just be "great".